# How to move a line of text file one line up in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files, line

I have a text file containing some Parameters and their values. After parsing it in python a Dictionary is created. Text file is something similar to:

```
Object1
 House: Blue
 Car: Red
Green
 Garden: Big

Object2
 House: Beatiful
 Car: Nice
 Garden: Small
```

After the Dictionary is created i also create some blocks which then help me to parse everything in json file. The Problem is that the "Green" is not detected as a value to car but as a new object. Therefore what I would like to do is to move the "Green" string one line up and to have a text file like this.

```
Object1
 House: Blue
 Car: Red Green
 Garden: Big

Object2
 House: Beatiful
 Car: Nice
 Garden: Small
```

How can I do this in Python? I was thinking of using regex functions to find the green but still I don't know how to put it one line up.

Piece of Code:

```
to_json = {}
answer = {}
block_cnt = 1
header = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]')
inner = re.compile("[\t]")
empty = re.compile("[\n]",)
with open(output, 'r') as document:
    for line in document:
        #print line

        if empty.match(line[0]):
            continue

        elif header.match(line[0]):
            if answer:
                to_json[block_cnt] = answer
                #print answer
                block_cnt += 1
                answer = {}
        elif inner.match(line[0]):
            _key, value = line.split(":  ")
            tab, key = _key.split("\t")
            answer[key] = value.strip("\n")
```

Comment: What is your current code to handle this text? And what are the criteria to handle the new lines, i.e. how does the newline get in there, are they consistent (easy to implement) or inconsistent (difficult to implement)?

Comment: can we see how dictionary looks like?

Comment: @mad_ i added part of the code

Comment: Does header follows a pattern like Object 1, Object 2 etc.?

Comment: @mad_ No, its different on each case, but that is not a problem for me. I reaname the header with the block counter so that when i conver in json i just get headers like 1 2 3 etc. The name of the header is not important for me. Thanks

Comment: @Idlehands I added a piece of the code. Hope that helps

Comment: The extraneous line will never begin with `\t` would it? If so you might just need to do an `else` clause to handle it.

Comment: No it would never begin with a tab. Could u tell me how can i write the else to fix that?

Comment: Got `NameError: name 'answer' is not defined`, please [edit]

Comment: @stovfl Hi, answer is the dictionary created, i just defined it here now because i had misscopied it from original program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:  I was thinking of using regex functions to find the green but still i dont know how to put it one line up.

One of your mistakes are `.match(line[0])`.
You match against the **first** character in `line`.
This is not what you want, change to `.match(line)`

> This results in the following Output:
>
> ```
> header:Object1   
> header:Green
> empty:
> header:Object2
> {}
> ```

Your `header = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]')` matches also the `Green`.
**How can you distingish between 'Green' and header?**

Your `inner = re.compile("[\t]")` matches nothing.
I suggest, change from `elif inner.match(line):` to `else:`